# replace the occurrence of character with a seq number using boost

Tags: c++, regex, boost

How can i replace multiple occurrences of a character with a string containing the occurrence number.
e.g if i have the following expression.

```
insert into emp values(?,?,?)
```

I want the following converted string.

```
insert into emp values(_p_1,_p_2,_p_3)
```

I am trying this using the boost regular expression.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this using the boost c++ (with no or minimum iteration).

currently I am using the following approach:

```
        std::wstring q=L"insert into emp values(?,?,?)";
        auto loc = q.find(L"?");
        auto len = wcslen(L"?");
        auto c=1;
        while(loc != std::wstring::npos)
        {
            q.replace(loc, len , L"_p_"+to_wstring(c));
            c++;
            loc = q.find(L"?");
        }
        cout<<q.c_str();
```

Please suggest better and efficient approaches.

Comment: The line `std::wstring q=insert into emp values(?,?,?)` is **not the real code**, since, lacking quotes and semicolon, it's very invalid. Secondly, since you're adding this after I posted my answer, it seems you failed to see that my answer is far more efficient (linear versus quadratic complexity). Third, this added info, showing that the values you want are *generated systematically* rather than arbitrary strings, partially invalidates the already posted answer. Tip 1: the string length of a single ASCII character will always be 1. Tip 2: to avoid the redundancy read up on "loop and a half".

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information.
I forget to mention the quotes in line 1.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just forget regular expressions and trying to do this simple thing with Boost.

It's like asking, "how do I add 1 to a variable using Boost regular expressions"?

Best answer, IMHO, is to instead just use `++` for the task of adding 1, and to use a loop to replace special characters with strings.

```
string const query_format = "insert into emp values(?,?,?)";
string const params[] = {"_p_1", "_p_2", "_p3"};

string query;
string const* p = params;
for( char const c : query_format )
{
    if( c == '?' ) { query += *p++; } else { query += c; }
}
// Use `query`
```

One might choose to wrap this up as a `replace` function.

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler.

---

If you control the `query_format` string, why not instead make the placeholders compatible with **Boost format**.

---

Re the parenthetical requirement

> **”** with no or minimum iteration

there's iteration involved no matter how you do this. You can hide the iteration behind a function name, but that's all. It's logically impossible to actually avoid the iteration, and it's trivial (completely trivial) to hide it behind a function name.